# Can I use vias and long trace between processor and 24MHz crystal?

Tags: transmission-line, microprocessor, crystal, via, trace

I have a situation where I can't put crystal (**24MHz**) close to the processor pin. As you see on the layout the trace between **crystal Y1** and **processor pins 46 and 47** is about **13mm** and there are **two vias** along the way. Top Layer is Red and Mid Layer 2 is Blue. More details on stackup below. I understand this is not recommended, but I'm trying to find if anyone has done something similar and what was their experience.

Before any layout changes are recommended, just adding some design constrains below:

1. Pin 1 and Pin 2 of processor are BLE antenna so I had to go around it on Mid Layer 2.
2. Processor is right against the left edge of the board so I can't put
   crystal to the left of processor. I can't move processor to the right either.
3. There are polygon pours in Top Later and Mid layer 2. I removed them on the picture to make the trace between crystal and processor clear.
4. I can't put components on Bottom Layer.

---

Details:

**Processor:** CC2640R2LRGZR from TI.
**Crystal:** ECS-240-8-36B2-CWN-TR from ESC Inc.
**Board Stack Up:** Top (Red), Mid Layer 1 (GND Plane), Mid Layer 2 (Blue), Bottom Layer (GND Plane)
**Trace Width:** 4 mils
**Via Size:** 8mils hole, 16mils diameter.

[image: Crystal Oscillator.]

Comment: Put a cap next to the oscillator. When you switch layers the return current will switch planes. Why are you using this stackup? You should always use signal, power, power, signal except when you really can’t avoid it.

Comment: You are asking about: "Is OK to make a board against the proposals that you find in all manuals?" . What answer do you expect?

Comment: At a minimum, put a 0V guard ring around the tracks. Is it a good idea? That’s why you build a prototype! If it turns out bad, then you have to reroute the board. Take the pain now or risk possible pain later. Also caps near the edge of the pcb is a recipe for production  problems. Ceramics crack.

Comment: @user110971 - I do agree with your layer stackup recommendation. There are large pin count components in the bottom later, taking almost the width of the board, so using it as a signal layer was not possible.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - I'm trying to find someone who had similar situation and were able to make it work without any problems originating from crystal. May be they had to match the trace length, or remove via stub, or trim the load capacitor in the processor, or simulate the tank circuit in SPICE software and add some passives......

Comment: @Kartman - There are polygon pours in Top Later and Mid layer 2. I removed them on the picture to make the trace between crystal and processor clear. This would be equivalent to 0V guard ring. I'm aware of the possibility for C8 to crack during board depaneling. I will have to work with manufacturer to use laser for depaneling.

Answer (score 3):

Had it been any other MCU, I would have said do a careful layout and you should be good to go. However, this is an RF MCU, any noise on the crystal signal will be coupled into your TX and RX signals, as the crystal directly drives the PLL and IF circuitry. I strongly suggest following TI's layout in this case.